# Which is more formal: clearer or more clear?

Tags: comparative-constructions, formality

I know both forms are correct, but I wonder which is more formal. Is there any difference in levels of formality?

Answer (score 1):

I would personally go with ***more clear***, if only because there is a common phrase that goes, "Things could not be more clear." But on the other hand, there is also the set phrase "clearer than day." It truly is a matter of personal taste, but I always felt ***clearer*** is slightly awkward-sounding -- and that ***more clear*** has a pleasing cadence. I'd say, for formal writing, you can't go wrong with ***more clear***. I think the Queen of England would agree.